# SQL - Multiple join left with sum doesn't give expected result

Tags: sql

Here is my request

```
SELECT j.* ,
    c.name as client_name ,
    s.name as supplier_name,
    s.ID as supplier_id ,
    mt.* ,
    SUM(pb.require_followup) as nb_followup,
    SUM(ws.worked_time) as hours_on_job,
    SUM(iv.total) as total_price,
    SUM(iv.hour_expected) as hours_planned,
    j.ID as ID 

FROM $wpdb->posts j
LEFT JOIN ".Job::$META_TABLE." mt ON mt.post_id = j.ID 
LEFT JOIN ".Job::$LINK_TABLE_JOB_CONTACT." l1 ON l1.job_id = j.ID 
LEFT JOIN ".Contact::$TABLE_NAME." c ON  c.ID = l1.contact_id
LEFT JOIN ".Supplier::$TABLE_NAME." s ON  s.ID = c.supplier_id
LEFT JOIN ".Problem::$TABLE_NAME." pb ON  pb.job_id = j.ID
LEFT JOIN ".Worksheet::$TABLE_NAME." ws ON  ws.job_id = j.ID
LEFT JOIN ".Invoice::$TABLE_NAME." iv ON  iv.job_id = j.ID

WHERE j.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND j.post_type = 'job'
    ".implode(' ',$where_condition)."
GROUP BY j.ID
ORDER BY j.post_date DESC
```

the Problem is that result for SUM is wrong when I LEFT JOIN other table.
The row 53 for example give `105` for nb_followup instead of `1`

Where this request return the right result simply by removing the last 2 LEFT JOIN : `LEFT JOIN ".Worksheet::$TABLE_NAME." ws ON  ws.job_id = j.ID` and
`LEFT JOIN ".Invoice::$TABLE_NAME." iv ON  iv.job_id = j.ID`

```
SELECT j.* ,
    c.name as client_name ,
    s.name as supplier_name,
    s.ID as supplier_id ,
    mt.* ,
    SUM(pb.require_followup) as nb_followup,
    j.ID as ID 

FROM $wpdb->posts j
LEFT JOIN ".Job::$META_TABLE." mt ON mt.post_id = j.ID 
LEFT JOIN ".Job::$LINK_TABLE_JOB_CONTACT." l1 ON l1.job_id = j.ID 
LEFT JOIN ".Contact::$TABLE_NAME." c ON  c.ID = l1.contact_id
LEFT JOIN ".Supplier::$TABLE_NAME." s ON  s.ID = c.supplier_id
LEFT JOIN ".Problem::$TABLE_NAME." pb ON  pb.job_id = j.ID


WHERE j.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND j.post_type = 'job'
    ".implode(' ',$where_condition)."
GROUP BY j.ID
ORDER BY j.post_date DESC
```

Also removing only `LEFT JOIN ".Invoice::$TABLE_NAME." iv ON  iv.job_id = j.ID` will give `15` as result for the row 53

To resume

Full request give `105` -> wrong should be `1`

removing the last join give `15` -> wrong should be `1`

removing the last 2 join give `1` -> Correct

Comment: The problem is that you are grouping by only the `ID` column, but you are selecting many other columns which do not appear in aggregate functions.  Your query is not logically well defined.

Comment: Agree with Tim Biegeleisen on this, your logic is not properly defined.

Comment: I'm not quite sure to understand, can you try to provide an answer?

Comment: I assume you are using MySQL because only that dbms allows GROUP BY with fewer non-aggregating columns than the SELECT clause. This is always bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate the SUM()s BEFORE you join, otherwise the rows multiply because of the joins and this in turn leads to errors in summation. e.g.

```
SELECT
      j.ID as ID 
    , pb.nb_followup
FROM $wpdb->posts j
LEFT JOIN (select pb.job_id, SUM(pb.require_followup) as nb_followup from ".Problem::$TABLE_NAME." pb GROUP BY pb.job_id) pb ON  pb.job_id = j.ID
```

The other problem you are facing is that MySQL permits "[lazy syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)" for group by. Don't use this lazy syntax or you will get unexpected error/bugs. It is very simple to avoid, REPEAT every column of the select clause in the group by clause UNLESS the column is using an aggregate function such as SUM(), COUNT(), MIN(), MAX() and so on.e.g.

```
select  a.col1, b.col2, c.col3 , sum(d.col4)
from a
inner join b on a.id = b.aid
inner join c on b.id = c.bid
inner join d on c.id = d.cid
group by a.col1, b.col2, c.col3
```